# dynamically hide/show button in highcharts

Tags: javascript, highcharts

**Highchart documentation** says that *if you want to disable the exporting buttons then we need to set the following property while before constructing the chart on the page*

```
 navigation: {
    buttonOptions: {
        enabled: false
    }
}
```

But once the chart is already rendered I want to disable one of the buttons based on some conditions, and enable them based on some other conditions on my page.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can disable the buttons after chart is rendered by calling update method of chart.navigation with new configuration. Here **chart** is the reference variable of rendered chart.Example is given below.

```
chart.navigation.update({buttonOptions: {
            enabled: false
        }})
```